# Biggest consecutive block-repeating in a binary string

Tags: combinatorics

in a binary string like $S="01011010101010101110111101001"$ you can ask that what is the size of the biggest consecutive block-repeating. for example in $S$ we have bellow blocks:

- $"1"$ : repeated 4 times consecutively.
- $"10"$ : repeated 6 times consecutively.
- and others

thus in $S$ biggest consecutive block-repeating is $6$. now the question is this:

for a binary string of length $n$ what is order of the lowest possible value for the biggest consecutive block-repeating number?

Comment: no. i want to find the lowest value for it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Thue-Morse sequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thue%E2%80%93Morse_sequence) is an arbitrarily long sequence which is "cube-free", meaning that there are no 3 consecutive blocks of the same pattern. Thus, the answer to your question is 2.

For a proof that the Thue-Morse sequence is cube free, see for example section 3 of [this paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCoQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.umb.edu%2F~offner%2Ffiles%2Fthue.pdf&ei=GmwoVNG7E8-uogT924HwBg&usg=AFQjCNFnogBv5fX0ARZYo7TrZnG7_wk3yw).